# Is it possible to set a default webcontent template in liferay?

Tags: templates, plugins, configuration, liferay, default

maybe you can help me.

I use verison 6.1.1 ce of liferay.

I have installed the "default-web-content-hook" from plugin-repo.

I want to set a default template for the webcontent display portlet, so that when a user clicks "Add Web Content" and the editor opens up, a certain preconfigured template, like "carousel" from the default-web-content-hook.

Anyone found out how it works?
Thanks guys, you're the best!
Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is no such option in Liferay which would set the default structure (template).

But it could be achieved in several ways.
You could just edit the link which opens the add web content dialog and append the structureId param with appropriate value.(&_15_structureId=MULTIPLE-ITEM-CAROUSEL)

Other option would be modify /portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/journal/edit_article.jsp and when the structureId param is null insert there a value. This value could be hard coded or supplied via configuration.

Also you could modify com.liferay.portlet.journal.action.EditArticleAction.